# Pythonic Ways of Importing Custom Modules?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've needed to deal with this for some time, but never really figured out what the most pythonic way of importing/setting up PYTHONPATH for custom modules is. I know I can use virtualenv to manage it, I know I can set it inside of scripts, or through pth files, but none of these seem very clean and pythonic to me, so I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Almost always, all custom modules I'm interested in are contained in the git directory I've cloned down that has whatever script I'm running, if that simplifies things.

I'm guessing virtualenv is the answer, but figured I'd ask in case I'm missing anything.

**EDIT:** To clarify, this is only a question about custom modules. I'm already using pip for modules from PyPI.

Comment: You can use pip to install packages that are not on PyPI also. You just need an URI endpoint and a valid python package. http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install

Comment: @HugoTavares Can you add that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pip to install packages that are not on PyPI also. You just need an URI endpoint and a valid python package:

Examples:

```
$ pip install https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/develop.zip#egg=pip
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pip.git#egg=pip
$ pip install git+git://github.com/pypa/pip.git#egg=pip
$ pip install /path/to/pip.tar.gz
$ pip install .
```

Read more at https://pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install

Comment: Are there good ways to add those local packages to requirements.txt to be installed on with pip install -r requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv is a good start.

There are also package managers like pip and easy_install that manage third party modules.

In code you can use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/customModule')
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv is the way to go with this.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then make a folder to setup your environments.  Inside that folder:

```
virtualenv <new_env_name>
```

That'll create a new folder in that directory, inside that there's a bin folder, run source on activate in that bin folder.  You can then do pip install  and it will only install it for that environment.

If you're cloning a git repo that you also want to be able to peruse the code easily (like if you're also working on that repo) clone it into your work_dir and then symlink or alias the package folder into the site-package directory inside that virtualenv's lib directory.  Otherwise, if it's packaged correctly if you do python setup.py install it should install it right for that virtualenv.